# Writing XML Elements w/ VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

XML Example:

```
<Options>
   <Directory Type="Install" Path="C:\temp"/>
   <xi:include href="Includes/Settings/StandardConsoleOutput.xml"/>
   <Option EnableMe = "true"/>
</Options>
```

I can successfully create the top level element (Options) but struggling with syntax of adding an element that matches the above 3 formats.

Any suggestions for writing elements of that structure or insight on how they're referenced so I can search better.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware of XML literals (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx)? Decide which namespace you need for the `xi:include` element and you can simply write the XML you want literally as you posted it.

Comment: Your xml is invalid since you don't have the namespace 'xi' defined.